# Loop through object

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need some help looping through an object I receive as JSON from an API, and assembling another object for a chart library.

Here is a sample of the object:

```
var channel_data = [
  {
    "27th Oct 12": {
      "xaxis": "27th Oct 12",
      "channels": {
        "Create and Craft": {
          "views": 13064,
          "bandwidth": 623136899214,
          "name": "Create and Craft"
        },
        "5 USA": {
          "views": 394,
          "bandwidth": 17889861768,
          "name": "5 USA"
        }
      },
      "totalViews": 25470,
      "totalBandwidth": 923866774348
    },
    "28th Oct 12": {
      "xaxis": "28th Oct 12",
      "channels": {
        "Create and Craft": {
          "views": 15298,
          "bandwidth": 860108829822,
          "name": "Create and Craft"
        },
        "5 USA": {
          "views": 500,
          "bandwidth": 28770314737,
          "name": "5 USA"
        }
      },
      "totalViews": 29377,
      "totalBandwidth": 1248778079465
    }
  }
]
```

I need to loop through this data and build the following array of objects to use with Highcharts rendering. Categories will be the dates and the data is the views for each date for each channel.

```
categories: ['27th Oct 12", "28th Oct 12"]

series: [{
  name: 'Create and Craft',
  data: [13064, 15298]
}, {
  name: '5 USA',
  data: [394, 500]
}, {
}]
```

I tried the following but ended up with the wrong structure;

```
 var dates = [], channels=[], views = [];

 for (var gdata in channel_data) {
     dates.push(channel_data[gdata].xaxis);
     for (var channel in channel_data[gdata].channels){
         channel_name = channel_data[gdata].channels[channel].name;
         channel_views = channel_data[gdata].channels[channel].views;
         channel_data = {"name" :channel_name,"views" : channel_views}
         channels.push(channel_data);
     }
     views.push(model.attributes[gdata].channels.name.views);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at underscore.js, it has a lot of helpful utility functions for collections and arrays

Comment: If you take a look this line `categories: ['27th Oct 12", "28th Oct 12"]` you will see that you have a sintax error.

Comment: Just a sugestion. You should format it on you backend. It could be very slow on client side.

Comment: This is not JSON, it's a JavaScript object (does not matter where it comes from). Your problem is not related to JSON at all.

Comment: Felix, thanks for the correction. Any ideas?
Richardo, yeah it's a mistake in writing out the expected output, it  is not part of the code, after processing the above object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var categories = [];
var series = [];
for(var i in channel_data) {
    categories.push(channel_data[i].xaxis); //your categories

    //same logic to loop through channels to populate series array
}
```

Comment: Never use a for...in loop on an array (`channel_data` is an array of objects)

Comment: channel_data[i] is an array of objects which contains channels data for each day so channel_data[i].xaxis is undefined.

Comment: Ok, this, was only a theory that could work, but it seems that i'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reduce the data structure into another form.

This can be achieved with helper utils like _ js (underscore js)

http://underscorejs.org/#reduce

Example taken verbatim from their website

```
var list = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]];
var flat = _.reduceRight(list, function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); }, []);
=> [4, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution used at the end of the day with help from AlanH's idea to use underscore.

```
  var channels = {};
            _.each(channel_data, function( date, i ) {
                _.each(date.channels, function( channel, i ) {
                    if ( channels[channel.name] === undefined ) {
                        channels[channel.name] = {
                            name : channel.name,
                            views : [],
                            bandwidth : []
                        };
                    }
                        channels[channel.name].views.push(channel.views);
                    channels[channel.name].bandwidth.push(channel.bandwidth);
                });
            });
```

I hope this helps anyone needing a similar solution.